# How can I compare these two strings in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, string-matching

So I need to compare a string against another string to see if any parts of the string match.  This would be useful for checking if a list of salespeople IDs against the ones that are listed to a specific GM or if falls outside of that GMs list of IDs:

```
  ID_SP         ID_GM         NEEDED FIELD (overlap)
  136,338,342   512,338,112         338
  512,112,208   512,338,112         512,112
  587,641,211   512,338,112         null
```

I'm struggling on how to achieve this.  I'm guessing some sort of UDF?

I realize this would be much easier to have done prior to using the for XML path(''), but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require me to unravel the data as that will blow up the overall size of the dataset.

Comment: Edit your question and provide your query and the sample data.

Comment: If possible. Fix your data structure.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not how you do it.  You would go back to the raw data.  To get the ids in common:

```
select tbob.id
from t tbob join
     t tmary
     on tbob.id = tmary.id and tbob.manager = 'Bob' and tmary.manager = 'Mary';
```

Comment: I agree, but if this was the task given, how would you approach it without using raw dataset.  Essentially these fields were appended to a dataset and handed to me.  To unravel this would create tons of duplicate data/rows.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data set isn't two raw sources, but one 'concatenated field' and a hardcoded string field that is a list of GMIDs (same value for every row) then the correct answer (from the starting point of the question) is to use something like nodes('/M') as Split(a).

Then you get something like this:

```
  ID_SP      ID_GM
  136        512,338,112
  338        512,338,112
  342        512,338,112
```

and can do something like this:

```
  case when  ID_GM not like '%'+ID_SP+'%'then 1 else 0 end as 'indicator'
```

From here you can aggregate back and sum the indicator field and say that if > 0 then the ID_SP exists in the list of ID_GMs

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You should append commas front and back and check for `'%,' + ID_SP + ',%'`. Otherwise you might find `123` in `4123`. This approach is rather hacky...

Answer (score 0):

-- Try This

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='512,112,208';

Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='512,338,112';

WITH FirstStringSplit(S1) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@String1,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)
,SecondStringSplit(S2) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@String2,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)

SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',' + part1.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM FirstStringSplit
    CROSS APPLY S1.nodes('/x') AS A(part1)
    WHERE part1.value('.','nvarchar(max)') IN(SELECT B.part2.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                                                  FROM SecondStringSplit 
                                                  CROSS APPLY S2.nodes('/x') AS B(part2)
                                                  ) 
    FOR XML PATH('')

),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon is correct, that you should not do this. This ought do be done with the raw data. the following code will "go back to the raw data" and solve this with an easy `INNER JOIN`.

The `CTE`s will create derived tables (all the many rows you want to avoid) and check them for equality (Not using indexes! One more reason to do this in advance):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,ID_SP VARCHAR(100),ID_GM VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('136,338,342','512,338,112')
,('512,112,208','512,338,112')
,('587,641,211','512,338,112');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT t.*
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.ID_SP,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS xml) AS PartedSP
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.ID_GM,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS xml) AS PartedGM
    FROM @tbl AS t
)
,SetSP AS
(
    SELECT Splitted.ID
          ,Splitted.ID_SP
          ,x.value('text()[1]','int') AS SP_ID 
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY PartedSP.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
)
,SetGM AS
(
    SELECT Splitted.ID
          ,Splitted.ID_GM
          ,x.value('text()[1]','int') AS GM_ID 
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY PartedGM.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
)
,BackToYourRawData AS --Here is the point you should do this in advance!
(
SELECT SetSP.ID
      ,SetSP.SP_ID 
      ,SetGM.GM_ID
FROM SetSP
INNER JOIN SetGM ON SetSP.ID=SetGM.ID 
                 AND SetSP.SP_ID=SetGM.GM_ID
)
SELECT ID
      ,STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + CAST(rd2.SP_ID AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM BackToYourRawData AS rd2
        WHERE rd.ID=rd2.ID
        ORDER BY rd2.SP_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CommonID
FROM BackToYourRawData AS rd
GROUP BY ID;
```

The result

```
ID  CommonID
1   338
2   112,512
```